# Use of the plural with list, and when item count is 0

Tags: grammatical-number, lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“user accounts” or “users account”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/user-accounts-or-users-account)

I keep asking myself which form is the most correct when listing items on a website:

- "Article list"
- or "Articles list"?

Also, when nothing was found, do you say:

- "No items were found"
- or "No item was found"
- or more simply "No item(s?) found?

Comment: Hi gregOire and welcome to the site. This is a two-part question, so it might be considered "too broad". Also, each part has numerous duplicates, which is a reason for closing. See e.g. [“user accounts” or “users account”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/) and [There are no comments / There is no comment.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. "Article list"
2. "No items were found"

Comment: FYI in English "plural" means "any number not 1", so 0 is plural.

Comment: @nohat: Remember, kids, this is one of the grammar rules we don't think about too hard so that we don't wind up stapling things to our foreheads and worshipping Cthulhu.