# “Nobody likes” or “nobody like”?

Tags: word-choice

What is the right way to say “Nobody like (likes) *doing something*”? What word I should use: like or likes?

Comment: [Possibly related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21556/40336)

Comment: Isn't this question a better fit for English Language Learners SE (http://ell.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that there is a such board on SE. Please excuse me for a wrong board choice.

Comment: What @caesarsgrunt said. *Learners* is still in "beta", so I can't closevote as "Off Topic, should be on ELL". I think it's Too Localised, since ELL is supposed to be concerned with questions of interest to *linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts*. The question of whether *nobody* is singular or plural doesn't fall into that category.

Comment: _Nobody_ is neither singular nor plural by semantics. So, by arbitrary grammatical fiat alone, it is always singular. Hence it takes the third person singular _-(e)s_ suffix on verbs in the present tense.

Comment: Well, I disagree. My question is **not** offtopic anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to say that nobody enjoys X, you would say "Nobody **likes** X."

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible meanings here:

1. *Nobody **likes** Jim* - in the sense that everyone *dislikes* Jim.
2. *There is **nobody like** Jim* - in the sense that Jim is an unusual (unique) character.
   This is independent of whether people generally like or dislike him.

#### Addendum:

OK, sorry, I've just noticed that the question was about *liking **doing** something*.
In that case, I agree with GetzelR's answer: it should be

*Nobody **likes** going to school [or whatever].*

Comment: 3. Imperative. 4. Subjunctive.