# How to explain why do we use, e.g. "1" video but "0" videos?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct plural form of a zero quantified noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/correct-plural-form-of-a-zero-quantified-noun)

It's getting really complicated when you have to explicate to a student a bunch of habitual *"Whys"*!

For example, how do I explain, why do we say: "1 video but 0 videos?".

It's understood, if we say 2 videos but when we refer to '0' why is it also plural?

Comment: Because only one is singular. Everything else is not singular. [The nature of singularity is being single, unitary, unique, isn't it? Everything else is plural.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/9796/300)

Comment: Also, what do you mean "it's understood if we say 2 videos"? I object. Many languages have dual. Some even trial or paucal. [Old Church Slavonic had dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(grammatical_number)#The_dual_in_the_Slavic_languages). Slovene still has, Russian does not. Going by your profile, your students are native speakers of Russian, so just ask them right back: why do they use plural for 2? It makes no sense! (^_^)