# It's "1 degrees" or is it "1 degree" outside?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say it's *1 degrees* outside or is it *1 degree* outside? (Talking about the weather in Buffalo, New York.)

Comment: Yes, either one. In rapid speech the "**1**" matters and the inflection doesn't. Think of it as being the "**°**" _degree_ mark after the number: "**1°, 21°**" are both the same.

Comment: I recommend "It's F***in' cold outside!"  :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct plural form of a zero quantified noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/correct-plural-form-of-a-zero-quantified-noun). As [the accepted answer there](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/13075/2637) says, *In English, **every number that is not 1 is considered plural**.*

Comment: Also I have to disagree with @JohnLawler on this; "*1°*" is always "one degree" and "*21°*" is always "twenty-one degrees" in the same way that *$1* is different than *$21*.

Answer (score 9):

No it is not correct.  1 is a singular unit, so at `1 degree` you are one unit above your zero point.

You can have 1 or -1 degree outside.  Anything else should be plural.

Answer (score -4):

I would say 1 degrees is correct. We are not discussing an amount of things. 1 is not number of degrees that exsist. It isn't the same as saying 1 cookie. Rather 1 is an idication of your possition on a scale called degrees. I would even venture that it is incorrect to say 1 degree celcius or fahrenheit.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether we are counting a number of degrees that exist or not. The number 1 always mandatorily takes the singular. You also did not do something one hours or one days ago. It is in no way incorrect to say it’s 1 degree, regardless of whether you’re talking Celsius or Fahrenheit, but the plural form would be considered ungrammatical by virtually all native speakers.