# '0 result' vs '0 results'

Tags: grammatical-number

I am developing a search control, where user types in and it returns search results. When I get no matching result what message would be correct in that case?

a)  0 result

b)  0 results

Comment: One is singular; all else is plural.  Your posting for duplicates record is now at 100%.  Please take the time to do your research first next time; it's rude to make other people do your work for you.

Comment: Zero is neither singular nor plural semantically. As a quantifier of _result_ it can modify either; depends, really, on whether one considers _result_ a count or mass noun in the context.

Comment: @tchrist I am extremely sorry about that but I did not know how to search for that, I even ended up attaching wrong tag. I am not very familiar to this site I am still learning. Thanks for helping me out. But of-course the link you pointed that has no concrete answer to my question.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is it common to write the digit 0 for negation of mass nouns? I’d always write “there’s no air here” not “there’s 0 air here” myself.

Comment: I searched for ***zero plural*** and found [zero quantified noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/correct-plural-form-of-a-zero-quantified-noun) which seems an exact duplicate.

Comment: Depends on the kind of writing you do, and what your audience expects, I spose. _Zero_ is a word that has a lot of impact, and I would usually spell it out for effect when using it for effect. But I can think of situations like _We tried every method we could think of to produce the condensate; output: 0.__