# Do I write "zero millimeter" or "zero millimeters"?

Tags: grammatical-number, measuring-units

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Correct plural form of a zero quantified noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/correct-plural-form-of-a-zero-quantified-noun)
>   [There are no comments / There is no comment.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/there-are-no-comments-there-is-no-comment)

In the sentence "There is 0 mm of attached gingiva,"  is the proper word "is" or "are" when asking about the millimeters?

Answer (score 1):

It's plural: **"How many millimeters?"**, and this is even if the number is 0.

There was a similar question but I couldn't find it, where the question was about numbers below 0.

Comment: I flagged it as a duplicate of this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/correct-plural-form-of-a-zero-quantified-noun

Comment: @z7sg: There was another one, which I commented (I didn't reply because it's not in my answers list)...

Comment: If it can't be found it's not a good question.  Then duplicates are inevitable.  I found that one straight away though.

Comment: @zysg: Yeah indeed, it was the first one... :| I'll flag it as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 millimetre and there are 0 or more millimetres

1 is singular
0 or anything but 1 is plural