# There is no ticket or there are no tickets?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There are no comments / There is no comment.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/there-are-no-comments-there-is-no-comment)

Can someone please tell me which one is better and correct.

```
There is no ticket.
or
There are no tickets.
```

If both are right, then which one is more preferable to say?