# Do you use singular or plural noun when there can be one or more of such nouns?

Tags: grammatical-number

Do you use singular or plural noun when there can be one or more of such nouns?

Example:

1. If you have over-sized items, you must pay for them in advance.

OR

2. If you have an over-sized item, you must pay for it in advance.

The meaning here is that if you have any number of over-sized items (one or more), you must pay for it or them.

Comment: _Luggage_ is a collective noun - we never say _luggages_.

Comment: That's a bad example, how about replace "check-in luggages" with "over-sized items"?

Comment: You could rewrite with "any over-sized items". Although it's also fine to say "If you have over-sized items, you must pay for them in advance" or "If you have an over-sized item, you must pay for it in advance". It depends what you want to emphasise.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you.  You should click the button to answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Items, etc.

In general, the grammatical number (singular or plural) must agree. For your examples:

> 1. If you have over-sized **items**, you must pay for **them** in advance.

The word *items* is plural, so to refer to the items, you say **them**.

> 2. If you have [an] over-sized **item**, you must pay for **it** in advance.

The word *item* is singular, so to refer to the item, you say **it**. It's also grammatically possible to say **him** or **her** if you are applying a grammatical gender, which is normally done only for persons or animals in English, but it is sometimes done stylistically for inanimate objects as well; see [Pronoun question: referring to inanimate objects as 'he' or 'she'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287721/pronoun-question-referring-to-inanimate-objects-as-he-or-she)).

### Luggage, etc.

If the noun is a mass noun with no unit of measure specified, the grammatical number is treated as singular:

> If you have over-sized **luggage**, you must pay for **it** in advance.

When we say a mass noun like **luggage** in that way, **luggage** and **it** refer to the whole collection of those things, even if it turns out that there are 3, 4, or 5 of them.

If the mass noun is combined with a unit of measure, then the grammatical number should agree with the grammatical number of the measure word:

> If you have **an** over-sized **piece** of luggage, you must pay for **it** in advance.
>
> If you have over-sized **pieces** of luggage, you must pay for **them** in advance.

### My family, Microsoft, CNBC, etc.

Some nouns are known as collective nouns and could themselves be treated as grammatically singular or plural, depending on the exact situation (e.g. *my family is big* vs. *my family are doctors*) and depending on regional conventions (e.g. in the U.S., *family* is conventionally used as singular and names of organizations are conventionally treated as singular, while in the UK, names of organizations are conventionally treated as plural).

See also: [Are collective nouns (and in particular companies) always given a plural verb form, or are certain ones treated as singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-and-in-particular-companies-always-given-a-plural-verb-fo)

### A number of, etc.

For the phrase "a number of" to indicate that there are several of something, I believe the dominant convention in all English-speaking countries is to treat the phrase/collection as grammatically plural, even though the measure word itself (number) appears to be grammatically singular. Thus,

> There **are** a number of houses.
>
> *There **is** a number of houses.
>
> A number of things still **need** to be done.
>
> *A number of things still **needs** to be done.

* = ungrammatical.

For the general case of "a X of Y", where X is a measure word, then you can use a singular if it makes sense (e.g. if you are counting, as in one X, two Xs, three Xs):

> There **is** a school of fish.

I believe you can also treat it as plural, though, if it makes sense (see above point about collective nouns):

> A school of fish **are** swimming.

### "one or more"

Phrases such as "one or more" are considered plural, despite the fact that the word *one* is singular:

> If you have **one or more** carry-on **bags**, please place **them** in the overhead container.

### "1+"

The notation *n+* is often used in writing to mean "the quantity n or more". In speech, you can read this notation as "n or more" or as "n plus" if you wish. The grammatical number of the resulting phrase is plural, even if n is 1, and regardless of how you read it aloud:

> If you have **1+** carry-on **bags**, please place **them** in the overhead container.

### n + m, n * m, etc.

When reading out maths problems, at least in American English, the whole expression is conventionally considered singular, regardless of the quantities involved and regardless of the operation involved:

> One plus one **is** two.
>
> Five plus seven **is** twelve.
>
> Six times seven **is** forty-two.

If you referring to more than one expression, or no expressions, then the expressions would be plural:

> One plus one and two plus two **are** two examples of addition problems.
>
> The problem is solved. There **are** no more expressions left.

See also: [Why is "zero" followed by a plural noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38293/why-is-zero-followed-by-a-plural-noun)